# Qt installer Framework : How to hide the selection of folder for installation

Tags: qt, qt-installer

How can I hide the select installation folder using qt installer Framework?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in a similar post here : [Qt installer framework: remove radio buttons from uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290010/qt-installer-framework-remove-radio-buttons-from-uninstaller/33170889?noredirect=1#comment56426726_33170889), I think the same answer can be used for your problem:

```
function Controller() {
    if (installer.isInstaller()) {
        installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.TargetDirectory, false);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this snippet but I'm pretty sure it will skip the "Target Directory page". Don't forget to add this script (let's say, controlScript.js) in your `config.xml` file :

```
<ControlScript>controlScript.qs</ControlScript>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the installer script, adding this line:

```
currentPage.TargetDirectoryLineEdit.enabled = false;
```